# How can we use IE and XDomainRequests while maintaining a drupal session?

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, sessionid, xdomainrequest

IE9's XDomainRequest does not send authentication or cookies (#5 in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2
010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitat
ions-and-workarounds.aspx).

We need to make all data requests within an authenticated / sessions context.

One general idea would be to add the session token explicitly to the XDomainRequest, and then on the backend use drupal's sess_read() to retrieve the session. 
However, the api advises against directly calling sess_read() quoting various undesired side effects ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21s
ession.inc/6 ).

Is anyone successfully using this or found another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a solution:

if the session context is lost (due to an anonymous request which only contains your $sessionKey), then we can retrieve the user session / user id with this:

```
$userFetched = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = '%s'", $sessionKey));

//assuming sessionKey was valid, then $userFetched->uid will contain the user's id.
```